# OpenGL Analyzer yells "redundant calls"

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I am using the GLKView and are submitting 3 textures with yuv-values.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + i);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        .....
```

In my draw routines is little code: only clear and draw

```
- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
}
```

It all shows fine, but the OpenGL Analyzer expert says "Renundant call" and if I click on it lists glBindFrameBuffer, glViewPort and glBindRendebuffer calls which isnt in my code, but in the GLKView class of Apple.

How can I get rid of this messages to optimize my code?